# SQLite database - cannot see updates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I have a sqlite database and I am adding to it new words. The problem is that I can see them added to a table only after restarting application. The "SELECT" statement doesn't "see" newly added elements before restarting application.

Why may this happen?

I am creating some kind of a dictionary. Here is how I add new items:

```
const char *sql_query = "INSERT INTO words(word) VALUES(?)";
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql_query, -1, &addWordsStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

sqlite3_bind_text(addWordsStmt, 1, [ word UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    if( sqlite3_step(addWordsStmt) != SQLITE_DONE)
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

sqlite3_reset(addWordsStmt);


sqlite3_finalize(addWordsStmt);
```

And here is my retrieval code:

```
const char *sql_query = "SELECT word FROM words WHERE id=?";

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql_query, -1, &getWordsStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) 
        {
            return;
        }

sqlite3_bind_int(getWordsStmt, 1, wordid);

    if( sqlite3_step(getWordsStmt) != SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error while getting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        sqlite3_reset(getWordsStmt);
        return;
    }

    NSString *word = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(getWordsStmt, 0)];

sqlite3_reset(getWordsStmt);

sqlite3_finalize(getWordsStmt);
```

Comment: How are you adding the words? How are you searching for them?

Show us the source!

Comment: I'd try NSLogging the result of every single sqlite3_ call, to see everything is expected, but your add code looks like it should probably work. What's your retrieval source look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are in a transaction.  There must be some other calls during your open and close routines that are wrapping your calls in a transaction and not displayed in your code fragments.

That is why you don't see the new words until you application exits

Answer (score 1):

There's your problem:

```
const char *sql_query = "SELECT word FROM words WHERE id=?";
```

This isn't how you use SQL. Instead, you should be using `SELECT word FROM words;` and stepping to get each row as long as you're getting `SQLITE_ROW` until you get `SQLITE_DONE`. That will get you all your words. How are you going to find a word by id when you don't know the id of newly added words?

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure that it is my problem. I know that id is being auto-increased, so if I have an amount of rows in a table I can get any row I want. That is not what is my problem about. How can I commit changes?

Comment: Unless the sqlite3_finalize() on your add is being called much later, they're already being committed. Your problem is a misunderstanding of how to get data out of SQLite. How do you count the words? How do you update how many words you expect to have?

Comment: tewha is correct and his explanation describes why you "see" the data when you restart.  Give his explanation a chance.

Comment: Rereading my last comment, I put an "unless" in there that didn't belong. You don't need to call sqlite3_finalize() to commit a change, that just frees the compiled statement. Commit is automatic regardless of that.