# How to commit changes in SQLite?

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I've got a problem in my database - somehow changes sometimes are not being autocommitted so I need to COMMIT the manually.

How can I do this? What code do I have to write in objective-C in order to commit changes in SQLite?

I am developing an iPhone application.

Thanks.

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667290/sqlite-database-cannot-see-updates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I just happened to write to another question, the simplest way is:

```
char* errmsg;
int result = sqlite3_exec(database, "COMMIT", NULL, NULL, &errmsg);
```

with the usual result codes &c (you'll need to sqlite3_free(errmsg) after you've used the error message it points to, if any).