# objective c - iPhone - replacing local copy of sqlite database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, sqlite, persistence

I use an sqlite database in my iPhone application, and during my applications life-time the user will likely add some new records to it.  My problem is this, when the user turns off the phone/closes application these records are lost and the application loads up the original version of the database without the added records.

What I would like to know is, is there any way I can replace the local copy of the database stored on the iPhone with the version the user essentially creates with the new records appended to it?  If I can't actually replace the database what would be the best course of action to take in order for the new records to persist?

Thanks,

Jack

EDIT:  The database is stored in the documents directory.

EDIT 2:

Basically, if the below code is run, how would I commit the changes made by the insert statement so that the applications main version of the database is updated rather than just the temporary copy?

```
-(void)insertData{

    sqlite3 *database;
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    //Get the path to the documents directory and append the databaseName
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSString *databasePath = [appDelegate m_DatabasePath];
    NSLog(@"%@", [appDelegate m_DatabasePath]);
    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        NSString *insertSQL = @"INSERT INTO products (name,category,calories, saturates,fat,fibre,sugar,salt, image) VALUES ('Snickers',' Confectionary','300','55','55','55','55','55', 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/88/Snickers_wrapped.jpg');";
        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL)== SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"Here 1");
            if(sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_DONE) 
            {
                //Create a new animal object with the data from the database
                Product *l_Product = [[Product alloc] initWithName:@"Snickers" category:@"Confectionary" calories:@"300" fat:@"55" saturates:@"50" sugar:@"10" fibre:@"50" salt:@"5" imageURL:@"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/88/Snickers_wrapped.jpg" ];

                //Add the animal object to the animals array
                [appDelegate.m_Products addObject:l_Product];

                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Product Added" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];    
                [alert show];

            }
            else 
            {
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Product Not Added" message:@"An error has occured" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];   
                [alert show];
                alert=nil;
            }   
        }
        // Release the compiled statement from memory
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);    
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your database ? In application bundle or documents directory ? if it is in application bundle you will lost data when app closes. You should create working copy of your db in documents directory if it is not there.

Comment: @NoMoreWishes Its in the documents directory - sorry, should have mentioned that - edited accordingly.

Comment: Post your code how you do transaction with your db. Please also post code for of how do you copy database at documents directory..

Answer (score 0):

The app'll have to **commit the changes** made by the user.

something like this (taken from a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053362/how-to-commit-changes-in-sqlite))

```
char* errmsg;
int result = sqlite3_exec(database, "COMMIT", NULL, NULL, &errmsg);
```

see the docs http://www.sqlite.org/search?q=commit

Answer (score 0):

If the SQLite DB is being replaced on relaunch then it's probably something you are doing incorrectly in the code.

Rather than shipping the SQLite DB inside the resources for the app, create the database dynamically.  Every time the app launches run some initialisation code to create the DB.  The statements should be along the lines of:-

```
create TABLE if not exists...
```

If you do this and connect to the database properly, then you should find that it works as a persistent store.

Don't forget that you will also need to create the database first (again, 'if not exists') and any indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You can supply your database in the app bundle, just be sure to copy the "bare" database to the documents directory before making changes (perhaps in the *appDidFinishLaunching* delegate method after startup). This will also enable the user to update the app in the future while still keeping his data intact.

Comment: But check that the database doesn't already exist before doing the copy, otherwise, it'll get overwritten.